# How do I parse json data from website into dictionary in python?

Tags: json, python-3.x, api

Can anyone teach me how to parse multiple json data from single url into dictionary?

the url is: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/elastic/examples/master/Common%20Data%20Formats/nginx_json_logs/nginx_json_logs

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your data is a stream of objects of this nature, but not well-formatted.

```
{"time": "17/May/2015:08:05:32 +0000", "remote_ip": "93.180.71.3", "remote_user": "-", "request": "GET /downloads/product_1 HTTP/1.1", "response": 304, "bytes": 0, "referrer": "-", "agent": "Debian APT-HTTP/1.3 (0.8.16~exp12ubuntu10.21)"}
```

First fetch the data

```
r = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/elastic/examples/master/Common%20Data%20Formats/nginx_json_logs/nginx_json_logs')
```

Then manually split the string to an array.

```
data = json.dumps(r.text)
arr = data.split("\\n")
```

Now `arr[0]` is the first object in your stream in a string format.

Keep using the keys here forward. And ofcourse the keys you use, don't have to have the same name as the ones in the stream.

Comment: I was doing this at the beginning then i realize the data are multiples json object, so i get this error. JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 239)